# Getting error with this code

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

when i am putting this code into .htaccess file for hide the .php extension am getting some error like
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

```
#Remove PHP extension from links
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f
RewriteRule (.*)/$1.php[L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}^[A-Z]{3,9}\/([^.]+\.)+php\HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$/$1[R=301,L]
```

Comment: Well just a tip for problems like this one - Just delete some rows until the code works and you'll know which one is making you the problem

Comment: What is in the apache error logs?

Comment: Please post logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copied this code from somewhere, but the spaces didn't copy with it. Therefore the flags and the first and second argument of `RewriteCond`'s and `RewriteRule`'s were stitched together. This is, of course, invalid syntax and produces a 500 Internal Server Error. You can find documentation for mod_rewrite [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Corrected syntax:

```
#Remove PHP extension from links
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+\.)+php\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank You Sumurai8
After provide the space between them its working correctly
thanks a lot.